# <p:watermark> appears unparsed in generated HTML source

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, watermark

I'm using JSF 2.0. I've been trying to render a placeholder for an input text, and I'm trying primefaces' watermark. Here's the jsf code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
....
....
<h:form>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <h:outputText value="Header"/>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h:inputText id="first" value="#{bean.firstValue}"/>
                    <p:watermark for="first" value="Fill me"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</h:form>
```

This is how it's rendered:

```
<form id="j_id_1v" name="j_id_1v" method="post" action"/mypage/app/main.xhtml" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    "Header"
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <input id="j_id_1v:first" name="j_id_1v:first" type="text" value>
            <p:watermark for="first" value="Fill me"></p:watermark>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

The value in #{bean.firstValue} is **null**. Not sure if that's alright, or if it should be an empty string. 
The problem is that the rendered input field is empty. No watermark. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: looks like you haven't properly included primefaes jar in your class path

Comment: I thought it was enough just by putting this in: xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui

Comment: Follow primefaces configuration instructions..

Comment: @Nacho321, you must add the primefaces jar too, just like you add the JSF jar/s

Comment: Yeah, you're all right: I have to add the jar, which sucks big time because I'm not allowed to add external jars. Welp, I'll see what can I do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the primefaces jar too, just like you add the JSF jar/s

p.s if you want to use watermark you can just use a [jquery watermark plugin](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery%20watermark&oq=jquery%20watermark&aqs=chrome..69i57j5j0l2j69i64.3028j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for that...